# C program - Structure variable data packing and alignment

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-alignment, struct-member-alignment

What will be the output of the program on a 32-bit machine (using GCC)? Explain.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

     struct node {
         int data;
         struct node *link;
     };

     struct node *p, *q;
     p = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
     q = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
     printf("%d, %d\n", sizeof(p), sizeof(q));
     return 0;
}
```

The output shows

> 4, 4.

Is the above program related to structure member alignment padding and data packing?

Comment: Use `%zu` to print a `size_t`, and as pointed out by others, you are printing the size of a pointer, try: `printf("%zu, %zu\n", sizeof(*p), sizeof(*q));`

Answer (score 3):

No, you are just printing the size of the *pointers*. It's not related to the internal member layout of structures.

Comment: Both `sizeof(p)` and `sizeof(q)` are equivalent to `sizeof (struct node *)` since `p` and `q` are both `struct node *`s.

Answer (score 2):

On a 32-bit system the stored addresses are always 32 bits big. If you're printing the size of a pointer you're basically just printing the size of the address it points to `(32 Bit -> 4 Byte)`.

If you want to know the size of the struct do something like this:

```
struct node p;
struct node q = {4, &p};

printf("%zu, %zu\n", sizeof(p), sizeof(q));
```

Answer (score 2):

- **Point 1** Use `%zu` format specifier to print the output of `sizeof` of type `size_t` .
- **Point 2** Note the type of `p`, it is `struct node *`, same as `q`.

So, essentially, `sizeof(p)` and `sizeof(q)` are exactly same as `sizeof(struct node *)`, which, on your platform are 32 bit wide. As you're not considering a *variable* here, so the alignment and padding for the structure and members are neither relevant nor involved in *this* case.

That said, please see [why not to cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Comment: `%zu` will not necessarily work on every system, suggest OP the alternative to use `%lu` in that case.

Comment: @shekharsuman no, I won't. `§7.21.6.1`, paragraph 7 prevents me from doing that. :-)

Comment: Then I'd fluently award you a downvote. I've experienced this problem in Dev C++, Windows,32 bit. You should accept criticism, and happily apply that in your answer...

Comment: @shekharsuman you're most welcome. If i'm getting down-votes for advising the _correct_ thing, i'm more than glad. Cheers !!

Comment: If you're not providing an alternative to OP for the special cases too, and if being advised by someone which you should, then you're pretty much rude guy. If you ask as a proof, then I can give you a proof too. BTW, I just asked you to make an edit revealing the exceptional cases too. It again, depends on your will to improve the answer.

Comment: [O'Reily's Understanding and using C pointers](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028000.do) book says `The recommended
format specifier is %zu. However, this is not always available. As an alternative, consider
using %u or %lu.`. And, I feel you and me can't be more superior than him(the author).

Comment: @shekharsuman: The advice to use `%u` or `%lu` is dodgy at best.  You'd have to fence it with `if (sizeof(size_t) == sizeof(int)) …use %u… else if (sizeof(size_t) == sizeof(long)) …use %lu… else …cry out in horror…`.  Frankly, there's limited excuse for not following at least the 15+ year old C99 standard that added `%zu` (and preferably the 3+ year old C11 standard).  The trouble is, MS is stuck in a 25+ year old time-warp w.r.t their C compiler.  It really is beyond time that MS updated their compiler.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler-Thanks for your feedback, I appreciate this. But, my point was to simply check exactly what you mentioned using if-else and then apply `%lu` OR `%u` only if `%zu` is not available. I agree that MS compilers are crap. But, I just requested the author to add this line as a suggestion...

Comment: @SouravGhosh- I feel I have done a terrible thing as I should haven't downvoted your correct answer. But, I also feel you shouldn't have enlarged this issue. Nevermind though, I am retracting my downvote, THANKS to SIR Jonathan Leffler, and I again apologise for doing such a childisch act. SORRY for editing your answer to remove my downvote(my vote is locked). I hope you're no more angry over me, and I will keep upvoting your answers as usual...

Answer (score 0):

> No, it is not related to the structure member alignment padding and data packing.

Since it is a 32-bit machine the size of any pointer will be `4` bytes. Since p and q are of type `struct node *` i.e. pointer to `struct node` the result prints size of pointers `p` and `q`.